# An even map from $S^n$ to $S^n$ must have even degree

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm working on Hatcher Problem 14 from Section 2.2.

> A map $f: S^n \rightarrow S^n$ satisfying $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$ is called an even map. Show that an even map $S^n \rightarrow S^n$ must have even degree, and that the degree must in fact be zero when $n$ is even. When $n$ is odd, show there exist even maps of any given even degree. [Hints: If $f$ is even, it factors as a composition $S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n \rightarrow S^n$. Using the calculation of $H_n\left(\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n\right)$ in the text, show that the induced map $H_n\left(S^n\right) \rightarrow H_n\left(\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n\right)$ sends a generator to twice a generator when $n$ is odd. It may be helpful to show that the quotient map $\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n / \mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^{n-1}$ induces an isomorphism on $H_n$ when $n$ is odd.]

What I have so far:

As in the hint, $f$ factors as $S^n \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n \xrightarrow{\bar f} S^n$, where the first map $p$ is the two sheeted cover. Since we know that $H_n(\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n)=0$ when $n$ is even and $\mathbb Z$ when $n$ is odd, we just need to consider the case when $n$ is odd. We need to show that $p_*:H_n\left(S^n\right) \rightarrow H_n\left(\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n\right)$ is "multiplication by 2." As in Hatcher 125, $H_n(S^n)$ is generated by the chain $\Delta_1^n-\Delta_2^n$, where $\sigma_i:\Delta_{i}^n\to S^n$ ($i=1,2$) correspond to the upper and lower hemisphere, with the boundaries glued together. Then we have
$$
p_*[\sigma_1-\sigma_2]=[p\sigma_1-p\sigma_2].
$$
Now, $H_n\left(\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^n\right)$ is generated by the characteristic map of its $n$-cell, call it $\Phi$. **What I don't understand is why $p\sigma_1=\Phi$ and $p\sigma_2=-\Phi$.**

Any help is appreciated! Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

To see that $p \sigma_1 = \Phi$ recall that $\mathbb R P^n$ is given its cellular structure by writing it as the quotient of the upper hemisphere by identifying the equator with itself by the antipodal map.

To see that $p \sigma_2 = -\Phi$, note that applying the antipodal map to $\sigma_2$ yields $\sigma_1$ with the reverse orientation.

I have attached a diagram of the situation when $n=1$.

[image]

Comment: I understand why $p\sigma_1=\Phi$, but I'm having trouble with the other equation. If $\sigma_2$ differs from $\sigma_1$ by the antipodal map, then $p$ doesn't notice this antipodal map, right? Then shouldn't it be $p\sigma_2=\Phi$?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: they differ by the antipodal map on the interior but agree on the boundary since they glue. Hence applying the antipodal map to $\sigma_2$ gives $\sigma_1$ with the reverse orientation.

Comment: Sorry but based on my understanding of your description, $\sigma_2:\Delta^n\to S^n$ is not even continuous. Say $n=1$, then $\sigma_2$ maps $0\in[0,1]$ to one of the points on the equator but maps $\varepsilon\in[0,1]$ to almost the other end of the circle.

Comment: In the case $n=1$ the inclusion $\sigma_1 \to S^1$ is the inclusion of the closed interval to the upper half of the circle, sending 0 to the rightmost point and 1 to the leftmost point (the equator is two points). The inclusion $\sigma_2 \to S^1$ is the inclusion of the closed interval to the lower half of the circle, sending 0 to the rightmost point and 1 to the leftmost point.

Comment: In particular, taking the quotient map $\sigma_1 \to \mathbb RP^1 \cong S^1$ gives a 1-simplex on the circle with the opposite orientation to that given by $\sigma_2 \to \mathbb RP^1 \cong S^1$.

Comment: @peeco Then $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ actually don't differ by an antipodal map. They just differ by a sign in the second coordinate, but not the first. The antipodal map reverses the sign in both coordinates.

Comment: To specify: their images inside of $S^n$ differ by the antipodal map. However, applying the antipodal map reverses the orientation on the boundary.